# Page source Unavailable when using headless browser in selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate a process with python to visit a website with my username and password and check whether some appointments options are available. The reprex code could be accessed [here](https://github.com/gabrielbdornas/reprex/tree/selenium-headless-unavailable-after-login).

The original code is shown below, and the selenium 4.11.2 works pretty well when the headless option is commented:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

load_dotenv()

# Replace these with actual values
login_url = 'https://prenotami.esteri.it/Services/Booking/2391'
login = os.getenv('LOGIN')
password = os.getenv('PASSWORD')
search_text = "Stante l'elevata richiesta i posti disponibili per il servizio scelto sono esauriti."

# Set up Chrome options for headless mode
chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

# Initialize the Selenium webdriver with the configured options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

# Open the login page
driver.get(login_url)
driver.get_screenshot_as_file("1_login_page.png")

# Find the login and password input fields and fill them
login_field = driver.find_element('name', 'Email')
password_field = driver.find_element('name', 'Password')
login_field.send_keys(login)
password_field.send_keys(password)

# Submit the form (you can replace this with actual form submission method if needed)
password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# Allow some time for the page to load and the login to complete
time.sleep(3)
driver.get_screenshot_as_file("2_message_page.png")

# Check page message
if search_text in driver.page_source:
    print('Closed appointment')
else:
    print("Open appointment")

# Close the browser when done
driver.quit()
```

The successful after-login-page could be seen in this [picture](https://github.com/gabrielbdornas/reprex/blob/5415d57eeca934526886fbfeeea2ce5af2cf71cc/2_message_page.png).

But, unfortunately, I must run the process with headless set to `True`. In this case, the source page shows only the text `Unavailable`, as we can see after [this commit](https://github.com/gabrielbdornas/reprex/tree/393b61427dc8bd758bb64a3a3dd476f38ca1e97d) onwards, which shows the [picture](https://github.com/gabrielbdornas/reprex/blob/393b61427dc8bd758bb64a3a3dd476f38ca1e97d/2_message_page.png) of the after-login-page.

[This Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69128870/why-cant-get-the-page-source-with-headless-browser-using-selenium) looks mostly mine case and the solutions suggests adding `User-Agent`, what I did but didn't work (actually I tried both Windows and Linux user agent options).

Then, I tried adding [many chrome options](https://github.com/gabrielbdornas/reprex/tree/4b6207f370bb2df03d2a11123ede8b5ea1f7814c/main.py) like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56074474/11755155), [used a wait process](https://github.com/gabrielbdornas/reprex/tree/f5d74848632c5578d39f6dc00453aac1bea3c0c9/main.py) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64311984/11755155) and even just [add `it` language](https://github.com/gabrielbdornas/reprex/tree/d7915b9ad14cb65d8b624fe16ca3e4f7930749b5/main.py) as another chrome option, but nothing worked.

What I'm missing here? It looks like the headless process is being blocked by the system. Am I right? If yes, it's another possibility to test besides what I've already done?

Answer (score 1):

Seemed like your site has anti-scrapping mechanism that detects if browser is in `headless` mode.

Use `UndetectedSelunium` driver to hide that you're in headless mode

[Reference](https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/)

```py
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from undetected_chromedriver import ChromeOptions

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = uc.Chrome(options)


driver.get("https://prenotami.esteri.it/Services/Booking/2391")
# your code
```

It's usually used to avoid CloudFlare / Captcha / headless mode detection.
In your case it also would work (I tested and was able to see page after success login)

Comment: Hello @Yaroslavm, thank you so much for your help. It worked when I started the driver as suggested by the documentation or `driver = uc.Chrome(headless=True,use_subprocess=False)`. It's still a little strange because if I run twice, the second one will fail. If I wait some minutes (15 for example) it works. Can you imagine why this is happening?

Comment: @GabrielBraicoDornas I tried to execute your code with undetected selenium 5 times in a row and each time it passed. Maybe, you had network problems / site was down?

Answer (score 0):

Since that site uses anti-selenium services, you can use https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase to reach the site:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(uc=True, headless=True)
driver.get("https://prenotami.esteri.it/Services/Booking/2391")
# ...
driver.quit()
```

(After `pip install seleniumbase` and running with `python`)